# Linear Estimation with iid and uniformly RVs

Tags: probability, distributions, estimation, random-variable, conditional-probability

I can't resolve the second point of the following

**Problem** Let $Y_i, X, V_i$ be scalar random variables $\forall i=1,2,\dots, p$, defined as follow:

- $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{x}, \sigma_x^2)$, i.e. $X$ is a Gaussian variables with expected value $\bar{x}$ and variance $\sigma_x^2$;
- $V_i \sim \mathcal{U}([-\delta, \delta])\quad \forall i=1,2,\dots, p$, i.e. all $V_i$ variables are uniformly distribuited over the interval $[-\delta, \delta]$;
- $V_i,\dots,V_p$ are independent each other;
- $V_i \perp X \quad \forall i=1,2,\dots, p$, i.e. all $V_i$ variables are uncorrelated with $X$;
- $Y_i\triangleq X + V_i \quad \forall i=1,2,\dots, p$.

For the following linear model 
$$Y\triangleq CX+V $$
where

$$Y\triangleq\begin{bmatrix}
    Y_1  \\ 
    \vdots  \\  
    Y_p     
\end{bmatrix} \quad V\triangleq\begin{bmatrix}
    V_1  \\ 
    \vdots  \\  
    V_p     
\end{bmatrix} \qquad
C\triangleq\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\ 
    \vdots  \\  
    1     
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^p$$

prove, under the hypotesis of $\sigma_x^2\to\infty$ (*no a priori information*), that

1. the MMSE estimation $\hat{x}_\text{MMSE}$ of $X$ based on $Y$ is
   $$\hat{x}_\text{MMSE}=\frac{y_+-y_-}{2}$$
   where $y_+\triangleq\max_{1\leq i \leq p}Y_i$ and $y_-\triangleq\min_{1\leq i \leq p}Y_i$;
2. the MSE $\hat{\sigma}_x^2$ of the previous estimation is
   $$\hat{\sigma}_x^2=\frac{6\sigma_V^2}{(p+1)(p+2)}$$
   where $\sigma_V^2\triangleq\delta^2/3$

**Proposed solution of point 2** By definition, the MSE in question is
$$\begin{align}\hat{\sigma}_x^2 &=\lim_{\sigma_x^2\to\infty}\int_\mathbb{R}(x-\hat{x}_\text{MMSE})^2 f_{X|Y}(x|y)\text{ d}x \\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}\left(x-\frac{y_+-y_-}{2}\right)^2 \lim_{\sigma_x^2\to\infty} f_{X|Y}(x|y)\text{ d}x\end{align}$$

so the problem consist in two steps: to find the conditional distribution $f_{X|Y}(\cdot)$ and then to calculate the previous integral. For the first step we can recall from probability theory the following result valid for linear models
$$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_V(y-Cx)f_X(x)}{\int_\mathbb{R}f_V(y-Cx)f_X(x)\text{ d}x}$$ 
where $f_V(\cdot)$ and $f_X(\cdot)$ are respectively the PDFs of $V$ and $X$.
The explicit expression of $f_X(\cdot)$ is clear 
$$f_X(x)\propto \exp\left[-\frac{(x-\bar{x})^2}{2\sigma_x^2}\right]$$
while for $f_X(\cdot)$ we can observe, for the mutual independence of the ${V_i}_i=1^p$, that
$$f_V(v)=\prod_{i=1}^p f_{V_i}(v_i)=\prod_{i=1}^p \frac{1}{2\delta}[1(v_i+\delta)-1(v_i-\delta)]$$
where $1(v_i)$ is the Heaviside step function over the real axis. It follows straightforward
$$f_V(y-Cx)=\prod_{i=1}^p f_{V_i}(y_i-x)=\prod_{i=1}^p \frac{1}{2\delta}[1(y_i-x+\delta)-1(y_i-x-\delta)]$$
The conditional distribution assume the following form
$$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^p[1(y_i-x+\delta)-1(y_i-x-\delta)]\exp\left[-\frac{(x-\bar{x})^2}{2\sigma_x^2}\right]}{\int_\mathbb{R}\prod_{i=1}^p [1(y_i-x+\delta)-1(y_i-x-\delta)]\exp\left[-\frac{(x-\bar{x})^2}{2\sigma_x^2}\right]\text{ d}x}$$
thus, taking the limit, we get
$$\lim_{\sigma_x^2\to\infty}f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^p[1(y_i-x+\delta)-1(y_i-x-\delta)]}{\int_\mathbb{R}\prod_{i=1}^p [1(y_i-x+\delta)-1(y_i-x-\delta)]\text{ d}x}$$
by observing that the productory is non-zero (is unitary) only over the intersection of the supports of the PDFs $f_{V_i}(\cdot)$, we can write
$$\begin{align}\lim_{\sigma_x^2\to\infty}f_{X|Y}(x|y)&=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^p[1(y_i-x+\delta)-1(y_i-x-\delta)]}{\int_{y_+-\delta}^{y_-+\delta}\text{ d}x} \\
&=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^p[1(y_i-x+\delta)-1(y_i-x-\delta)]}{y_--y_++2\delta}\end{align}$$ 
Now the second step. We have
$$\begin{align}\hat{\sigma}_x^2 &=\int_\mathbb{R}\left(x-\frac{y_+-y_-}{2}\right)^2 \lim_{\sigma_x^2\to\infty} f_{X|Y}(x|y)\text{ d}x \\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}\left(x-\frac{y_+-y_-}{2}\right)^2 \frac{\prod_{i=1}^p[1(y_i-x+\delta)-1(y_i-x-\delta)]}{y_--y_++2\delta}\text{ d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{y_--y_++2\delta}\int_{y_+-\delta}^{y_-+\delta}\left(x-\frac{y_+-y_-}{2}\right)^2 \text{ d}x\end{align} $$
it turns out that, whatever is the value of the integration, the result is independent from $p$, so my conclusion is wrong

Comment: You should mention that you had posted this question before on [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2815890/321264) but did not receive any feedback so far. One should avoid cross posting.

Comment: Besides [not X posting], you should have the self-study tag and indicate the source of this exercise.

Comment: The exercise is from lecture notes of my course "Estimation and Identification"